# Using Postgres FK from jsonb with Hasura?

Tags: postgresql, graphql, jsonb, hasura

We have foreign keys within a json blob in postgres. We join with these like so:

```
SELECT f.id, b.id FROM foo AS f
  LEFT JOIN bar AS b ON f.data -> 'baz' ->> 'barId' = text(b.id)
```

I'm now trying out Hasura to do som graphql queries and I need these as object relationships. In the UI I can only try to manually add relationships with normal columns, not nested json data:

[image]

Is it at all possible to get a graphql relationship this way?

Comment: You can use a Hasura "computed field" to add this relationship. Check out the docs here: https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/schema/computed-fields.html#table-computed-fields

Look at the parts of the docs where computed fields return "table" types.

Comment: You can see an example using "computed field" here: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/3462#issuecomment-561663839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer in comments, thanks @iamnat. I'll just evolve here with my example for clarity since I still struggled a bit:

Super simple schema and data as such:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

CREATE TABLE foo
(
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    name text,
    data jsonb NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE bar
(
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    name text,
);

WITH bars AS (
  INSERT INTO bar (name) VALUES ('bar') RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO foo (name, data) VALUES ('foo', jsonb_build_object('barId', (SELECT id FROM bars)));
```

I then can create a function for the relationship:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo_bar(foo_row foo)
RETURNS SETOF bar AS $$
  SELECT *
  FROM bar
  WHERE text(id) = foo_row.data ->> 'barId'
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

This I can then use in Hasura as a computed field under "Data" -> foo -> Modify -> Computed fields -> "Add a new computed field". Just give it a name and reference the function in a dropdown:

[image]

I can then query:

```
query MyQuery {
  foo {
    name
    foo_bar {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

with expected result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "foo": [
      {
        "name": "foo",
        "foo_bar": [
          {
            "name": "bar"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```